# Reason code = "1".. SQLCODE=-846, SQLSTATE=42815

Tags: db2, sequence, auto-increment

```
create TABLE STUDENT_TEMP
(
    USER_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
             (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE NO CACHE ORDER),
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CITY VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY  (USER_ID)
 );
```

I want to insert auto increment column with sequence in db2.
try to use this code from ibm site.
but haven't got correct code yet.

Comment: [Right from the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n846.dita): "*reason-code 1: the underlying data type of the identity column or sequence object is not supported. Identity columns and sequence objects support the following data types: SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT, and DECIMAL (or NUMERIC) with a scale of zero.*".

Answer (score 2):

Change the USER_ID to an integer or another numeric data type because VARCHAR is not a supported data type for identity columns.

`create TABLE STUDENT_TEMP
(
    USER_ID int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
             (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE NO CACHE ORDER),
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CITY VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY  (USER_ID)
 );`